# How can I delete group in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

In our organisation we recently moving to git, I have created a group accidentally I would be appreciate if there is a way to delete this group.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the most recent version (Mar. 2019):

1. At top bar, click on `Groups`.
2. Type part of the name of the desired group or click on Explore Groups. Click on the desired group.
3. Go to `Settings > General`
4. Expand `Path, transfer, remove`
5. At the bottom of page you find `Remove group`. Click on the button and type the name of the group to activate `Confirm` button. Then click on `Confirm` to delete the group.

Answer (score 8):

On the recent version (per posting date 11.4.4) navigate to your group's

```
Settings > General > Advanced > Expand
```

There you will find the `Remove group` button.

Comment: On Gitlab.com (I think this is 11.7 at the moment) use **Settings > General > Path, transfer, remove > Expand** to find the "Remove group" button.

Comment: but this doesn't remove the group.  it merely schedules it for removal.  I want to actually have it removed

Answer (score 0):

The group deletion has changed with [GitLab 14.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/02/22/gitlab-14-8-released/#delete-groups-at-the-parent-group-level) (February 2022)

> ### Delete groups at the parent group level
>
> In this milestone, we’ve worked on one of the initial steps to reach feature parity between group owners (in any installation base) and administrator-only functionality that exists solely in the administrator panel for self-managed users.
>
> Group owners can now delete a group and its subgroups from the parent group level. Until now, group owners had to go into each individual group to delete them, which was timely and inefficient. Group owners can now view all groups and delete them from a single place.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_8/del_group.png -- Delete groups at the parent group level]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/#remove-a-group) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/349863).

---

Note: [GitLab 15.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/09/22/gitlab-15-4-released/#api-support-for-immediate-group-deletion) (September 2022), but only the non-free version, comes with:

> ### API support for immediate group deletion
>
> You can now use the API to immediately delete individual subgroups. Prior to this release, you could only delete individual subgroups from group settings in the UI.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#remove-group) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/360008).